# XtraGrid. apply filter by enter key

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, devexpress, xtragrid

I use devexpress XtraGrid and auto-row feature. At documentation I see:
"You can also specify whether filtering should be applied immediately after changing a value or only when end-users press the ENTER key."
I would like implement second behaviour, but I don't find any properties for this.
So how can I achieve this behaviour? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On KeyDown event handler, use the code below

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
// Your filter code.
}
```

If you need more help, please be more specific. (Post some codes etc.)